# Бесячая "беда" с Intillij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Некоторое время назад наша любимая среда разработки начала добавлять 2 пустые строки вместо одной:

```
myMethod(arg) {
  |  
  |
}
```

вместо

```
myMethod(arg) {
  |
}
```

На что уже жалуются [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010094/intellij-idea-blank-lines-after-opening-brace-formatting/28011168#28011168) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733987/intellij-adding-extra-line-in-new-blocks). Лекарства пока нет. Что будем делать?

Comment: ждать ебилдо....
ммм... переходить на eclipse )))
а вообще надо писать баг-репорты разрабам, заводить треды на офф форуме. Быть может это не баг а фича такая? Ну а если баг то быстро пофиксят и сделают патч/апдейт

Comment: А через live code нельзя шаблон свой задать? Я так понимаю, проблема выявляется, когда используется автоформатирование?

Comment: @dimka3210, нет. Когда потом жмёшь ctrl + alt + L , при соответствующих настройках, он выправляется. Эта фигня выскакивает именно в момент написания

Comment: А в техподдержку, в техподдержку-то писали? Blank lines в code style дергали?

Comment: @Dazar, тогда скорее всего можно пофиксить через настройки

Comment: @Etki пару часов назад написал, жду ответа. Дёргал. Не помогает.  
@dimka3210, ни у меня, ни у тех ребят со стаковерфлоу не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всему виной плагин Gauge.